# Is Quillen's bracket a "universal enveloping" something?

Tags: ct.category-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, groupoids

$\newcommand{\G}{\mathcal{G}}$
In K-theory, there is a construction due to Quillen as follows. Let $(\G, \oplus, 0)$ be a monoidal groupoid. Then the bracket $\langle \G, \G \rangle$, sometimes also denoted as $U\G$, is a new category. Its objects are the same as the objects of $\G$. For $A,B$ such objects, the hom set is:
$$\hom_{U\G}(A,B) = \operatorname{colim}_{X \in \G} \hom_\G(X \oplus A, B).$$
In less abstract terms, a morphism from $A$ to $B$ is an equivalence class of pairs $(X,f)$ where $X \in \G$ and $f : X \oplus A \to B$ is a morphism in $\G$. Two such pairs $(X,f)$ and $(X',f')$ are deemed equivalent if there exists $g : X \to X'$ such that $f' = f \circ (g \oplus \operatorname{id}_A)$.

(For example, if $(\Sigma, \sqcup, \varnothing)$ is the groupoid of finite sets and bijections, then $U\Sigma$ is the category of finite sets and injections, usually denoted $\mathsf{FI}$ or $\Theta$. If $\G$ is the groupoid of finitely-generated free $R$-modules and isomorphisms, then $U\G$ is the category of fg free $R$-modules and "free split injections".)

Under some condition, $\G$ is the underlying groupoid of $U\G$. The notation $U\G$ (that I have found in papers of Randal-Williams–Wahl and Soulié, and it certainly appears elsewhere) definitely suggests that this is the "universal enveloping... something" of $\G$. Is there such an interpretation? Or is this just an artifact of notation?

Comment: Universal enveloping means it is the left adjoint of some forgetful functor. Since it is defined as a colimit, by adjoint functor theorem it does have a right adjoint which is probably a forgetful functor.

Comment: What's the forgetful functor from categories to monoidal groupoids? And $U\G$ is defined by a colimit inside $\G$, not inside groupoids. I do not really see how to prove that $U$ preserves colimits of monoidal groupoids...

Comment: I just wanted to give an idea, sometimes people, when define something with colimits they denote it by U and when it is defined by limit they denote by F which I think comes from the adjoint functor theorem but it doesn't necessarily have a interpretation by forgetful functors or universal enveloping. But here could be something deeper going on.

Comment: Here is one fact. In some (maybe all?) cases, functors from UG to set are equivalent to modules over the free associative algebra on one element in the monoidal category of G sets.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I like to think about it.

- Let $\mathcal G$ be a monoidal groupoid.
- Let $\mathbb B \mathcal G$ be the delooping of $\mathcal G$: this is a $(2,1)$-category with one object $\bullet$.
- Let $\mathcal X$ be a groupoid that $G$ acts on.
- Then the action of $\mathcal G$ on $\mathcal X$ may be thought of as a (pseudo)functor $\chi_{\mathcal X} : \mathbb B \mathcal G \to \mathsf{Gpd}$, which sends $\bullet$ to $\mathcal X$.
- Let $\mathbb E_{\mathcal G} \mathcal X \to \mathbb B \mathcal G$ denote the fibration of $(2,1)$-categories classified by $\chi_{\mathcal X}$. One way of thinking of this is that $\mathbb E_{\mathcal G}$ is the lax colimit of the functor $\chi_{\mathcal X}$ in $(\infty,1)$-categories.

> Then $\langle \mathcal G, \mathcal X\rangle = \tau_{\leq 1} \mathbb E_{\mathcal G} \mathcal X$.

Here $\tau_{\leq 1}$ is the 1-truncation: it takes homotopy classes levelwise to turn a $(2,1)$-category into a 1-category. As a left adjoint, $\tau_{\leq 1}$ preserves colimits.

> So $\langle \mathcal G, \mathcal X\rangle$ is the lax colimit of the functor $\chi_{\mathcal X}: \mathbb B \mathcal G \to \mathsf{Cat}$.

In particular, when $\mathcal X = \mathcal G$ with the left translation action, then $\mathbb E_{\mathcal G} \mathcal X$ deserves to be called $\mathbb E \mathcal G$, and we have

> $\langle \mathcal G, \mathcal G \rangle = \tau_{\leq 1} \mathbb E \mathcal G$ is the lax colimit of the tautological functor $\mathbb B \mathcal G \to \mathsf{Cat}$.

I'm still not sure conceptually why one wants to apply $\tau_{\leq 1}$, rather than viewing everything as taking place in $\mathsf{Cat}_\infty$. But at some point I did write some notes for myself developing parts of Grayson's Higher Algebraic K-Theory II from this perspective, and it seemed to be not a terrible perspective to take.

Comment: What do the angle brackets denote?

Comment: The angle brackets are as in the question statement, slightly generalized. $\langle G, X \rangle$ has the same objects as $X$, but $Hom_{\langle G, X\rangle}(a,b) = \varinjlim_{g \in G} Hom_X(g \cdot a, b)$. This notation is from Grayson's _Higher Algebraic K-Theory II_.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the main reason that Grayson / Quillen introduce this construction is to define $G^{-1} G = \langle G, G \times G \rangle$ where $G \times G$ has the diagonal action. The point is that $G^{-1} G$ is a model for the group completion of $G$. More generally, they define $G^{-1} X = \langle G, G \times X \rangle$, which universally extends the action of $G$ on $X$ to an action of $G^{-1} G$. So this is a localization construction.